# mod_rewrite RewriteRule is not working always

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i make the following condition work if there is no number, so it can handle www.example.com/en/fourthcategory as well as www.example.com/en/fourthcategory/8562

```
RewriteRule en/fourthcategory/([0-9]+) ?l=en&c=c4&p=$1 [L]
```

i could use two rules, but would prefer using only one, since in the end there would be double as much rules and there will be quite a lot of categories in at least four languages...

```
RewriteRule en/fourthcategory/([0-9]+) ?l=en&c=c4&p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule en/fourthcategory ?l=en&c=c4 [L]
```

or is this not the right approach to create RewriteRules for every possible category separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule en/fourthcategory/?([0-9]*) ?l=en&c=c4&p=$1 [L]
```

Be carefull, with http://www.example.com/en/fourthcategory/8562, you'll get a final URL like this:

```
/index.php?l=en&c=c4&p=8562
```

index.php can be any DirectoryIndex filename of your apache server.

Comment: this did the trick. it works. i simply cannot mark your answer as useful due to my reputation value